# Full metal alchemist kanji in latex code

Tags: unicode, japanese

I want to write 鋼の錬金術師 (aka "Alchemist of Steel") is latex.  I have the CJK package but just a simple copy and paste of the above kanji to gvim does not do the trick. The code I have is

```
\begin{CJK*}[dnp]{JIS}{min}
Fullmetal Alchemist (鋼の錬金術師 Hagane no Renkinjutsushi, literally "Alchemist of Steel")
\end{CJK*}\end{document}
```

What I get is the error:

```
./preface.tex:56: Package CJK Error: Invalid character code.
```

I may have missed something vital though... Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Because I can view this properly in UTF-8 html, I think the problem is that the input is not in JIS encoding. You probably need `{UTF8}` instead of `{JIS}` to get rid of the `Package Error` (but I have no idea whether or not you need to set up fonts)

Comment: If I save that text with `euc-jis-2004` (that's Emacs slang for JIS-2004), the output is correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's probably an encoding problem. If I save the example in UTF-8 encoding changing it into

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
Fullmetal Alchemist (鋼の錬金術師 Hagane no Renkinjutsushi, literally "Alchemist of Steel")
\end{CJK}
```

I get correct output. Check the encoding used by gvim. However with

```
\newcommand{\japanesetext}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}#1\end{CJK}}
```

in the preamble, typing the phrase as

```
Fullmetal Alchemist (\japanesetext{鋼の錬金術師} Hagane no Renkinjutsushi,
literally "Alchemist of Steel")
```

seems more practical.

Comment: `CJK*` environment ignores the spaces after CJK characters. It is better to use `CJK` environment here.

Answer (score 1):

Inputting Japanese is quite a pain, as far as I know.

Rather than a direct solution using CJK, I suggest, if you can, a way round, using platex:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
Fullmetal Alchemist (鋼の錬金術師 Hagane no Renkinjutsushi, literally "Alchemist of Steel")  
\end{document}
```

and then `platex foo.tex` followed by `dvipdf foo.dvi` (or maybe `dvipdfmx foo.dvi`) if you need pdf output.

However, this might prove problematic if you use packages incompatible with platex.